# concatenate values of one column to single text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

my Column is like this:

col1

Mary

Jack

John

and i need to get something like this:
Mary,Jack,John

I did it by using "For XML PATH", but the problem is that segment not work in SQL server view,
is there other way to get concatenation of one column?

Comment: try this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1585

Comment: You should make that an answer instead of just a comment

Comment: I am irrationally excited by having learned that trick just now.  You definitely should make that an answer.

Comment: let me post this as an answer

Comment: @APH please upvote it if you think its a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using SQL **[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)** experession to convert your column values into a comma separated string.

here's what you need to do.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
  SampleCol varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Test
  VALUES ('Test')
INSERT INTO @Test
  VALUES ('Test 1')
INSERT INTO @Test
  VALUES ('Test 2')
INSERT INTO @Test
  VALUES ('Test 3')
INSERT INTO @Test
  VALUES ('Test 4')

DECLARE @aa varchar(200)
SET @aa = ''

SELECT
  @aa =
  COALESCE(CASE
    WHEN @aa = '' THEN SampleCol
    ELSE @aa + ',' + SampleCol
  END
  , '')
FROM @test

SELECT
  @aa
```

here's a complete **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1585)**

Comment: Well, this works, but I'd prefer the "FOR XML" approach. Because it is completely inline. With this approach you could retrieve 1:n data as JOIN (as APPLY in fact), and create concatenated columns delivered in one column of a SELECT's resultset on the fly...

Comment: yeah we could do that too but he asked for another approach.

Comment: the OP needs this in a view. How would he use your approach there? The inline approach allows this (ad hoc), even for many rows in one go. Finally your "trick" has nothing to do with COALESCE, rather with @x=@x+ISNULL(column,'') which has been possible ever since. Never mind, happy coding

Comment: thak you @PouriaSharif :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Mary'),('Jack'),('John');
SELECT
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ', ' + col1
        FROM @tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,2,'')
```

Comment: The original question says `for xml path` won't work for him.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that "segment not work in SQL server view", but this must be a lack in syntax,,, I use this approach everywhere. On the other hand the COALESCE approach with declared variables won't work in a VIEW for sure - unless you wrap it within a multi-statement-UDF wich is a bad practice,,, This "trick" with COALESCE was running long before COALESCE just by using SELECT @aa=@aa + ISNULL(x,y,) FROM somewhere ......